# Vuex rootActions with several modules

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a vuejs on client side, where I use vuex for state management. I have several modules (in separate files) but some of the modules, has very similar actions, that's why I want to create [dry code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

**My goal:** Creating a root action, what can be called by every modules.

My main vuex looks like this:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  actions: {
    rootactions,
  },
  modules: {
    users,
    classes,
    studentgroups,
    // ... other stuff
  }
})
```

How should I refer the rootactions methods?

Thanks for the responses in advance!

Comment: see Module Reuse part at
https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html

Comment: interesting idea, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about to create a separate file RootActions.js with the common actions

```
export default {
    action1: () => {
        //
    },
    action2: () => {
        //
    },
}
```

And then import it in your module file e.g. User.js

```
import RootActions from './RootActions'

const state = {
    // state object
}

const mutations = {
    // mutations object
}

const actions = {
    // actions object
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions: Object.assign(RootActions, actions)
}
```

Comment: Hey! Its a good idea, I'll give it a chance. I'm going to write about the solution!

Comment: Hey! I guess it will be the solution. Thanks!

Comment: just edited the answer to add new actions to the module or rewrite root ones

Comment: Nice one! destructuring would do the trick too `{...RootActions, ...actions}`

Answer (score 7):

"To dispatch actions or commit mutations in the global namespace, pass { root: true } as the 3rd argument to dispatch and commit."

{
   root: true
}

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html

Comment: This is the correct way to dispatch root actions from a different module. Should be marked as correct answer.